# Hide a specific Dev element with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to remove this footer from my page by specifying only this section to display: none

Eg: "div class="poweredby" display: none" but I'm not sure how to do it...
Here is the Div class I would like to assign the attribute to

```
<div class="poweredby">
    <p class="report">If this site is spam or abuse,
        <a id="reportLink" target="_blank" href="https://app.grate.cm/grate/report.html?site=301708&url=https://app.grate.cm/grate/builder/301708#/">report here.</a>
    </p>
    <p class="poweredby-text">This site was built with <a href="https://grate.com" target="_blank">SEMTotal</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are your efforts to solve this, what did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: Do you have a separate style sheet? What did you try?

Comment: seems like you havent learned basic css, you need to learn the basics of css first and you will be able to do this easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
<div class="poweredby" style="display: none">
...
</div>
```

You can either set the attribute directly via `style` attribute like the code above or within separate .css file like the code below

```css
.poweredby{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first one messed up the entire layout of the page.
The second one worked like a charm on a PC, but on the mobile phone it didn't change anything. I noticed this inside the <style> section

@media (max-width: 991px) {
            .poweredby {display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; }

How can I remove this as well?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well thats strange, because basically its the same , anyway:

You can only have either display: flex or display: none ...
How should it behave on the mobile phone?

Comment: Seems to have a mobile attribute when the window exceeds 991px the display changed from flex, to none with the code you have given me...
Therefore everything that is smaller than 991px still shows the footer.

Comment: I see I see ... then you just need to add it to media queries ...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use javascript to hide an element like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.poweredby').style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.hide{display:none;}
</style>    
<div class="poweredby hide">
    <p class="report">If this site is spam or abuse,
        <a id="reportLink" target="_blank" href="https://app.grate.cm/grate/report.html?site=301708&url=https://app.grate.cm/grate/builder/301708#/">report here.</a>
    </p>
    <p class="poweredby-text">This site was built with <a href="https://grate.com" target="_blank">SEMTotal</a>.</p>
</div>
```